# Shortcut to close an editor group by number in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have four editor groups open. I would like to close editor group three.
Can I bind a shortcut that targets group three?
ex. 
`Ctrl + X + G + 3` kills group three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a macro extension, try:[multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).  There is no built-in command that allows you to kill a specific group.  you can only kill the current group, other groups or all groups.  But you can create a macro that focuses a specific group and then kills that group:

```
{
  "command": "multiCommand.closeGroup3",
    "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.focusThirdEditorGroup",
        "workbench.action.closeGroup",
    ]
},
{
  "command": "multiCommand.closeGroup2",
     "sequence": [
         "workbench.action.focusSecondEditorGroup",
         "workbench.action.closeGroup",
     ]
},
```

and then set a keybinding in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "shift-alt-3",
  "command": "multiCommand.closeGroup3"
},
{
  "key": "shift-alt-2",
  "command": "multiCommand.closeGroup2"
},
```

I choose that keybinding because yours, `Ctrl + X + G + 3`, triggers a `cut` action first and `ctrl-g` is also bound to other commands.

So you would have to set up similar multiCommands to close the other editor groups but it should be pretty easy.